# NSLayoutAnchor not working with UIScrollViews inside UITableViewCell

Tags: swift, uitableview, uiscrollview, autolayout, ios9

I'm attempting to refactor code that programmatically creates autolayout constraints on a UIScrollView that is a subview of a UITableViewCell's contentView but am getting some unusual effects.

Code snippet being replaced is:

```
let scrollViewHorizontalConstraints =
NSLayoutConstraint.constraintsWithVisualFormat("H:|[sv]|",options: [], metrics: nil, views: viewDictionary)
viewConstraints.appendContentsOf(scrollViewHorizontalConstraints) /// scrollviewConstraints is an array!
let scrollViewVerticalConstraints =
NSLayoutConstraint.constraintsWithVisualFormat("V:|[sv]|", options: [], metrics: nil, views: viewDictionary)
```

I should be able to replace this with the new iOS9 UILayoutAnchor API as follows:

```
scrollView.leftAnchor.constraintEqualToAnchor(contentView.leftAnchor).active = true
scrollView.rightAnchor.constraintEqualToAnchor(contentView.rightAnchor).active = true
scrollView.topAnchor.constraintEqualToAnchor(contentView.topAnchor).active = true
scrollView.bottomAnchor.constraintEqualToAnchor(contentView.bottomAnchor).active = true
```

However, this code fails (no errors). Constraints are not built correctly - the resulting scrollView matches the height of the superview but not the width despite the fact that it has a subview constrained to the width of the UITableViewCell contentView. The original version works without errors.

Building the same structure inside a standard UIView using the new notation works so I'm suspicious of a bug but any suggestions would be gratefully received.

Comment: Have you tried to inspect the contentSize property of your scroll view?

Comment: Just checked - contentSize values match those shown using the view debugger in XCode: height 34pt , width 0pt

Comment: I've just built a small test app which stripped out much of the custom implementation of the scrollview and the constraints are being constructed correctly. This would suggest there is some conflict in the code that's not immediately obvious - I'll continue re-implementing functionality and see what happens

Comment: Could you please try setting the content size explicitly?

Comment: Explicit setting of content size doesn't help either (and, as it happens, would break my implementation for different size classes and orientations anyway). Thanks for the suggestion though

Comment: Ok, that must be a bug in the Interface Builder tool or something. Glad to know that you managed to overcome the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This appears to be a bug somewhere in Xcode. I've actually created a new project and built the autolayout code (using UILayoutAnchor) from scratch and it works. I've ensured the code is a verbatim copy of that used originally so can only assume it's gremlins in the system somewhere. Odd but Xcode can be like that sometimes!